# run function only inside specified div class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run a function only inside a specified div however currently it executes on the whole page. What is wrong with my code?

What I'm trying to achieve is that if I click any of the buttons, only the button that I clicked should hide and only one line of 'Some text' should appear.

Js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.product-1').each(function () {
        hidePersonaliseButton();
    })

    jQuery('.product-2').each(function () {
        hidePersonaliseButton();
    })

    function hidePersonaliseButton() {
        jQuery('.btn-personalise').on('click', function () {
            jQuery('.btn-personalise').hide();
            jQuery('.show-me').fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="product-1">
    <div class="personalise">
        <button type="button" title="button" class="btn-personalise">Button</button>
        <div class="show-me">
            <p class="personalisation">Some text 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-2">
    <div class="personalise">
        <button type="button" title="button" class="btn-personalise">Button</button>
        <div class="show-me">
            <p class="personalisation">Some text 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.show-me {
    display:none;
}
.product-1 .show-me {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.product-2 .show-me {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

See my jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sfv3Le1w/1/

Comment: jQuery(this).hide();

Comment: Your `.each` statements are unnecessary. You can simply run the contents of `hidePersonaliseButton` with the modifications in the below answers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4paqk3p7/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sfv3Le1w/2/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.product-1').each(function () {
        hidePersonaliseButton();
    })

    function hidePersonaliseButton() {
        jQuery('.btn-personalise').on('click', function () {
            jQuery(this).hide(); // hide this element
            jQuery(this).siblings('.show-me').fadeIn(); // hide sibling .show me class
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: calling the `hidePersonaliseButton` is not required, you can directly attach the `click` handler to the buttons class `btn-personalise`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any of those js codes what you have written, just the below code will work for you.

**Whats wrong in your approach:**

- actually what you were doing was attaching the `hide` functionality to each of the target sections, but the same can be done by directly attaching the `click` handler to the buttons class `btn-personalise`.

**JS Code:**

```
jQuery('.btn-personalise').on('click', function () {
        jQuery(this).hide();
        jQuery(this).siblings('.show-me').fadeIn();
 });
```

[Here is the corrected JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/sfv3Le1w/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caLnej9w/1/

Try this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-personalise').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
        $(this).hide();        
    });
});
```